# Is there any way by which I could change the color of cell and date onclick in fullcalendar in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I need to change the color of cell and its corresponding date as I click on it in fullcalendar. Is there any way to achieve both together as I click on it. Till now I have done it by using changing of cell background using .fc highlight where I mention the background color but here I am not able to change the color of the date, Where the date is still displayed as in default color.

```
style.css
.fc-highlight {
    background-color: rgb(13, 113, 224) !important;
    color:  #fff !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
```

Comment: I already gave you suggestions on this last time you asked it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65839175/i-need-to-display-the-selected-date-in-header-in-fullcalendar . Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

I have a little trouble to figure out the problem but it may be a problem of CSS rules overriding the color: black !important

Try to put it in

```
::ng-deep { 
.fc-highlight {
    background-color: rgb(13, 113, 224) !important;
    color:  #fff !important;
    display: block !important;
  } 
}
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I have done it but it still does not do any thing.
Is there any other way by which it can be achieved.

Comment: Try to look at this post, I have the impression that it fits with what you want to do :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55338595/12673585

Comment: I have covered that post before but there also only the background color of cell changes but not the color of date